# How to reassign current ajax request to a different request? - jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry, I didn't know how to put the question better. Basically, what I want is, if 2 similar ajax calls are fired before the 1st is finished, instead of sending the second one, just wait for the first one to complete and use that result.

As an example, you can think of an app, which requests Facebook news feed.

1. User goes from home screen to news feed page
2. ajax fires to get news feed content from Facebook
3. user clicks back button, which takes him back to home screen before ajax call is finished
4. user clicks on news feed again
5. ajax fires again to get news feed
6. meanwhile the first request comes back, but is no longer used, because the app is now listening for the second request, which is almost identical

I am saving the news feed content so that I can show it next time user comes to that page, while sending ajax call to update the content. But in the above case, the second time user comes to the page, the values are not saved yet, hence nothing to show before second request comes back.

Assume that it's a one page app, so we don't lose state.

I know it requires good amount of thinking. Any ideas? at least in theory?

Comment: When you say "clicks the back button" is this actually the browser back button taking him away from the current page or a button within the page which is doing something with javascript.  This matters because when you leave a page your javascript objects are gone.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: "Assume that it's a one page app, so we don't lose state". No it's not a browser's back button, it's a just a button, which onclick loads the home page view

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable = 0 when the page loads.  When a request is triggered - if the variable != 1 - fire off the request.  Once you have retrieved the requested and output the results; set it back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we don't lose state store the results of the ajax call somewhere and when the news feed is loaded again check if the results already exist before making the request again.

Comment: I am already doing that. But if the request is fired while the ajax call is being completed (no result returned yet).